# Update objectchoice field list on Blackberry

Tags: arrays, blackberry, drop-down-menu, updates

I'm new to Blackberry and I'm currently working on it. I have an ObjectChoiceField that uses a string array as its dataset. How can i update the display of the ObjectChoiceField list based on the change of array elements? 
I want to do similar thing like notifyDataSetChanged() on Android development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your ObjectChoiceField instance (let say `myObjectChoiceField`), via [setChoices(String[] newChoices)](http://tinyurl.com/cbn3v9w) method. Assume `newChoicesStringArray` is a String array with new option values.

```
     Application.getApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             myObjectChoiceField.setChoices(newChoicesStringArray);
         }
     });
```

`invokeLater()` is used to avoid UI event locking upong field update action.